# Does Google consider as duplicate percent encoded URL with different cases (upper and lower)?

Tags: seo, google

We have the following two URLs:

1. `https://example.com/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82`
2. `https://example.com/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82`

Both are identical except the the case (upper vs lower).  Will Google consider them to be duplicate URLs or it does not matter?

Comment: The HTTP spec says that there are two case insensitive parts of URLs: the domain name and percent encoding.   If Google is following the spec, it shouldn't treat them as different URLs, however, I don't have any experience or evidence that they do things correctly.

Comment: Not that it answers your question per se, but a solution would be to ensure that your canonicals reference the "decoded" version of the URL. If you have `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/тест">` then it's not only clear to search engines which version to index, it's clear to human visitors/searchers what you're actually serving.

Comment: See also: [Does URL encoding create duplicate content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31499/does-url-encoding-create-duplicate-content) which isn't about the case sensitivity, but about characters that can optionally be encoded.